# How can I safely share objects between Rust and C++?

Tags: rust

One way to construct and destruct C++ objects from Rust is to call the constructor and return an `int64_t` pointer to Rust. Then, Rust can call methods on the object by passing the `int64_t` which will be cast to the pointer again.

```
void do_something(int64_t pointer, char* methodName, ...) {
    //cast pointer and call method here
}
```

However, this is extremely unsafe. Instead I tend to store the pointer into a map and pass the map key to Rust, so it can call C++ back:

```
void do_something(int id, char* methodName, ...) {
    //retrieve pointer from id and call method on it
}
```

Now, imagine I create, from Rust, a C++ object that calls Rust back. I could do the same: give C++ an `int64_t` and then C++ calls Rust:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub fn do_somethind(pointer: i64, method_name: &CString, ...) {

}
```

but that's also insecure. Instead I'd do something similar as C++, using an id:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub fn do_something(id: u32, method_name: &CString, ...) {
    //search id in map and get object
    //execute method on the object
}
```

However, this isn't possible, as Rust does not have support for static variables like a map. And Rust's `lazy_static` is immutable.

The only way to do safe calls from C++ back to Rust is to pass the address of something static (the function `do_something`) so calling it will always point to something concrete. Passing pointers is insecure as it could stop existing. However there should be a way for this function to maintain a map of created objects and ids.

So, how to safely call Rust object functions from C++? (for a Rust program, not a C++ program)

Comment: Your map solution isn't safer than using pointers, even worse if either sides run multiple threads. Also it is much slower (hashing + lookups).

Comment: Not sure why you would use `int64_t` to store a pointer. In the first place you should use `uintptr_t` to match the pointer size (and `usize` on the Rust side), but also, why convert to integer in the first place? Just use `void *`/`*mut c_void`.

Comment: Serious question: Where did you get the idea that Rust doesn't have support for static variables? You can trivially make immutable and atomic static variables even with just the standard library, and `lazy_static` lets you easily create mutable statics of any type. One of the [top voted Rust questions on SO](/q/27791532/3650362) is about how to do so. I'm just asking because I have seen several people repeat the falsehood that Rust doesn't have statics. If you read this somewhere (in a tutorial, or documentation or something) maybe it can be corrected.

Answer (score 5):

#### Pointers or Handles

Ultimately, this is about *object identity*: you need to pass *something* which allows to identify *one instance* of an object.

The simplest interface is to return a Pointer. It is the most performant interface, albeit requires *trust* between the parties, and a *clear ownership*.

When a Pointer is not suitable, the fallback is to use a Handle. This is, for example, typically what kernels do: a file descriptor, in Linux, is just an `int`.

#### Handles do not preclude strong typing.

C and Linux are poor examples, here. Just because a Handle is, often, an integral ID does not preclude encapsulating said integer into a strong type.

For example, you could `struct FileDescriptor(i32);` to represent a file descriptor handed over from Linux.

#### Handles do not preclude strongly typed functions.

Similarly, just because you have a Handle does not mean that you have a single `syscall` interface where the name of the function must be passed by ID (or worse string) and an unknown/untyped soup of arguments follow.

You can perfectly, and really *should*, use strongly typed functions:

```
int read(FileDescriptor fd, std::byte* buffer, std::size_t size);
```

#### Handles are complicated.

Handles are, to a degree, more complicated than pointers.

First of all, handles are meaningless without some repository: `33` has no intrinsic meaning, it is just a key to look-up the real instance.

- The repository *need not* be a singleton. It can perfectly be passed along in the function call.
- The repository *should likely* be thread-safe and re-entrant.
- There may be data-races between usage and deletion of a handle.

The latter point is maybe the most surprising, and means that care must be taken when using the repository: accesses to the underlying values must *also* be thread-safe, and re-entrant.

(Non thread-safe or non re-entrant underlying values leave you open to Undefined Behavior)

#### Use Pointers.

In general, my recommendation is to use Pointers.

While Handles may *feel* safer, implementing a correct system is much more complicated than it looks. Furthermore, Handles do not intrinsically solve ownership issues. Instead of Undefined Behavior, you'll get <strike>Null Pointer</strike> Dangling Handle Exceptions... and have to reinvent the tooling to track them down.

If you cannot solve the ownership issues with Pointers, you are unlikely to solve them with Handles.